# "Step" attribute not working on datetime-local

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to use `datetime-local` to pick both date and time.

The input works okay, unfortunately I can't seem to get the `step` attribute to work at all.

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) seem to suggest I should be able to use it to set a step in seconds, however [this just isn't working at all](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-silence-lt76h?file=/index.html).

```html
<form method='post' action='#'>
    <input
      type="datetime-local"
      id="meeting-time"
      name="meeting-time"
      value="2018-06-12T19:30"
      min="2018-06-07T00:00"
      max="2018-06-14T00:00"
      step="900"
    />
<input type='submit' value='Go!'>
</form>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please paste your code here in the question in case your link dies.

Comment: By not working, do you mean you just don't see any stepper buttons? I don't see them in your example on Edge or Chrome. It's very patchy support... looks like the answer below can see them.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these only come into play when validating on submission and not in the actual UI itself. As @Toby support is patchy.

Comment: @John on Google Chrome the step attribute works on the input itself directly rather than on the input at form submission.

Comment: I'm saying there is no step. The calendar opens up but all the minutes are there. Is that what should be happening?

Comment: Is the step only supposed to work on the input itself rather than on the calendar that pops up?

Comment: @Eight Yes, I doesn't appear to  apply to the pop-up calendar and support on the input itself seems to vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Ah, well I guess that answers that. I was very confused by everyone saying it worked  Thank you either way for clarifying!

Comment: That is very confusing indeed!  Why on earth step is not presented in the UI?  If I want a date time that changes every hour I need a custom component?

Comment: @FredGuth That's what we ended up going with, unfortunately it's slim pickings out there for good date/calendar components :/

Comment: The step isn't working like I expect either. I would expect to see only minute choices of 00,15,30,45 etc in the minute dropdown selector.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, my confusion came from the fact that `step` doesn't change the steps that appear in the calendar nor stops users from typing the time in themselves.

The `step` attribute does "work" in loosest sense possible in that it allows users to step between values with arrows after selecting them with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be your browser. The [CanIUse website](https://caniuse.com/input-datetime)  states that `datetime-local` is not currently supported by Firefox, IE, or Safari.

I have run your example code in Google Chrome 86 and it works correctly with a step of 15 minutes.

I have run your code in Firefox 82 and the input box acts as a `text` input type rather than as a `datetime-local` type.

Comment: I'm on Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (x86_64) and it's not working at all. Tested on macos and windows.

Comment: `86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)` On this version, the up and down arrows scroll the time value by the step amounts. You can still manaully enter a non-stepped time value such as `22`.

Comment: Right I think the misunderstanding was that I expected the steps to work in the calendar in the calendar. Thank you for replying :)

Comment: @Eight The current HTML spec does not agknowledge if incorrect time values are put into that input. Your best bet would be to check this data by whatever receives the form.

Answer (score -5):

Step attribute value should be in seconds. In your example, you have given it as 900 which translates to 15mins. Your example in codesandbox works as expected.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#step)

For datetime-local inputs, the value of step is given in seconds, with a scaling factor of 1000 (since the underlying numeric value is in milliseconds). The default value of step is 60, indicating 60 seconds (or 1 minute, or 60,000 milliseconds).

Comment: How does this help? OP has already quoted the documentation and provided code which follows the docs, which isn't working for him. Telling him it does work, and quoting the docs again, isn't really seeking a solution. It's probably a browser version thing.

Comment: @Toby I forgot to quote i am using chrome browser 86 which Eight mentioned. I am not telling him the solution. I m just stating it works and this is the doc says. 